# NodeJS running on cpanel

Tags: node.js, cpanel

I recently found this article (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-scale-node-js-applications-with-clustering) and I was wondering if when running a nodejs application on cpanel, I have to write the code to spin up more processes using the cluster module. Or does cpanel or hosting provider takes care of that?